# validation doesnot working in MVC4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, data-annotations

I am making a sample MVC4 project in VS2012.. where i want some validations on the text box field ..but unfortunately it never works ,, I am posting my files,

My FriendController

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using validators.Models;

namespace validators.Controllers
{
    public class FriendController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Friend/

        public ActionResult Create()
        {

            return View();

        }
    }
}
```

my model class person.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    namespace validators.Models
    {
        public class person
        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage="must")]
            [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage="blah")]
            public string Firstname { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Lastname { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

and i am adding strongly typed view .... that generates following create.cshtml

```
@model validators.Models.person

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>person</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Lastname)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Lastname)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@*@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}*@
```

when i am running this project and enter submit button without any values in text box,, there is no validation message.... Help is appreciable

Comment: you are talking out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }` in your view. If this helpes then in means that validation is turned off in a `web.config` file.

Also verify that your scripts are included in next order:

1. jquery
2. jquery.validate.js
3. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: Where to add this in view

Comment: @Jatt.net, before `@using (Html.BeginForm())`

Comment: Sorry same issue again

Comment: @Jatt.net, please include scripts section of your layout in a question

Comment: wooooooooooo solved.... :) by adding jquery.min,.js file . 2,3 no. files already added...  thanks denys

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48592/discussion-between-jatt-net-and-denys-denysenko)

Answer (score 1):

Web.config file

```
<configuration> 
    <appSettings> 
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
    </appSettings>
```

Either in Global.asax file

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true; 
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

Ensure that JS files are (jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js)

Comment: done with these too .. but not solved the problem yet :(